# bootstrap select box reduce length

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Im using the below code in w3schools to build a select box in bootstrap, it works fine but it spans really long..

How can I reduce the size of the select box?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Form control: select</h2>
  <p>The form below contains two dropdown menus (select lists):</p>
  <form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="sel1">Select list (select one):</label>
      <select class="form-control input-small" id="sel1">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <label for="sel2">Mutiple select list (hold shift to select more than one):</label>
      <select multiple class="form-control" id="sel2">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add a style in the bootstrap select and select the width of your choice eg: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cV1HQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your select box in a div with class `col-{type}-{size}` according to bootstrap grid system.

Example:

```
<form role="form">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="sel1" class="col-sm-5 control-label>Select list (select one):</label>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <select class="form-control input-small" id="sel1">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

These links will help you:

[Bootstrap Grid System Reference](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

[Bootstrap Forms Reference](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)